# WPF expand content to outside the window

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I want to get the following effect in wpf

The main window looks like following
[image: Main window]
When you click on friends panel friends list should be expanded to outside the window
[image: Friends expanded]

And when I click on item from that list I have to be able to catch that event and handle on main window
How to achieve that in wpf?

I've tried to use expander, but it isn't showing content which doesn't fit the size of window. It's just showing the part of content

Comment: you can probably do something similiar with the proper setup on a custom window style http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/131515/WPF-Custom-Chrome-Library

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `Popup` control and set its `PlacementTarget` and `Placement` depending on which Button is clicked. Simple example:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>

    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Popup StaysOpen="False" Width="300" Height="200" x:Name="MyPopup">
        <Popup.Child>
            <StackPanel Background="Bisque"></StackPanel>
        </Popup.Child>
    </Popup>

    <Button Margin="25,25,0,25" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="100" Click="ButtonBase_OnClick">First</Button>
    <Button Grid.Row="1" Margin="25,25,0,25" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="100" Click="ButtonBase_OnClick">Second</Button>
    <Button Grid.Row="2" Margin="25,25,0,25" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="100" Click="ButtonBase_OnClick">Third</Button>

</Grid>



    private void ButtonBase_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        MyPopup.IsOpen = false;
        MyPopup.PlacementTarget = sender as UIElement;
        MyPopup.Placement = PlacementMode.Right;
        MyPopup.AllowsTransparency = true;
        MyPopup.PopupAnimation = PopupAnimation.Fade;
        MyPopup.IsOpen = true;
    }
```